# Parity node0: generate_seal: FAIL: Accounts secret key unavailable

Tags: parity

I've followed the [PoA tutorial](https://github.com/paritytech/wiki/blob/master/Demo-PoA-tutorial.md) and the two nodes seem to be communicating but `node0` keeps on logging this error message:

```
2018-04-06 17:22:10  generate_seal: FAIL: Accounts secret key unavailable.
2018-04-06 17:22:15  Imported #11 7a07…ab31 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 0.53 ms, 0.56 KiB)
2018-04-06 17:22:20  generate_seal: FAIL: Accounts secret key unavailable.
2018-04-06 17:22:30  generate_seal: FAIL: Accounts secret key unavailable.
2018-04-06 17:22:39     1/25 peers     16 KiB chain   12 KiB db  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync  RPC:  1 conn,  2 req/s, 113 µs
```

`node1` isn't logging it.

```
2018-04-06 17:22:15  Imported #11 7a07…ab31 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 0.90 ms, 0.56 KiB)
2018-04-06 17:22:16     1/25 peers     12 KiB chain   12 KiB db  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync  RPC:  1 conn,  2 req/s, 142 µs
```

What could it be?

The config is like [in the demo](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-poa-tutorial).

node0.toml:

```
[parity]
chain = "parity-poa.json"
base_path = "/tmp/parity0"
auto_update = "none"
[network]
port = 30303
[rpc]
port = 8545
cors = ["http://localhost/", "https://remix.ethereum.org/"]
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[ui]
port = 8180
[websockets]
port = 8645
[account]
password = ["node.pwds"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0x00Bd138aBD70e2F00903268F3Db08f2D25677C9e"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

node1.toml:

```
[parity]
chain = "parity-poa.json"
base_path = "/tmp/parity1"
auto_update = "none"
[network]
port = 30304
[rpc]
port = 8546
cors = ["http://localhost/", "https://remix.ethereum.org/"]
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[ui]
port = 8181
[websockets]
port = 8646
[ipc]
disable = true
[account]
password = ["node.pwds"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0x00Aa39d30F0D20FF03a22cCfc30B7EfbFca597C2"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

node.pwds:

```
node0
node1
```

Running Parity/v1.9.5/x86_64-windows-msvc/rustc1.24.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: node1 won't log it because the error is only for node0, even if they may exist on the same machine they are different entities, and don't share logged data. As for the error, I would make sure that your keyfile for node0 is `1) in the correct path` `2) actually exists` `3) has the proper permissions` I find it unlikely that the issue is related to parity software, since node1 is operating perfectly fine.